# InvocationTargetException when I add fx:controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've checked a couple other posts, but wasn't able to find an answer.  I'm getting an error (InvocationTargetException) when I add a controller and onAction tag to a button.  Maybe someone can spot the error?  It loads the fxml form if I remove the fx:controller within the pane tag and the button onaction attribute to the button.  Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="phonebook.UI.UI">
    <children>
      <TableView layoutX="199.0" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="401.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="106.0" text="First Name" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="90.0" text="Last Name" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="110.0" text="Number" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="94.0" text="Address" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <TextField fx:id="txtPhone_number" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="275.0" promptText="Phone Number" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtAddress" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="310.0" promptText="Address" />
      <Button fx:id="btnAdd" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="355.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnAddPerson" text="Add" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtSearch" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="82.0" promptText="Search by name" />
      <Button layoutX="127.0" layoutY="120.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Search" />
      <Button layoutX="450.0" layoutY="355.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Update" />
      <Button layoutX="517.0" layoutY="355.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Remove" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtLastName" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="240.0" promptText="Last name" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtFirstName" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="205.0" promptText="First name" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Phone Book" textFill="#aeacac">
         <font>
            <Font size="31.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

And...

```
package phonebook.UI;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import static javafx.application.ConditionalFeature.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class UI implements Initializable{

    //FXML Variables
    @FXML
    private TextField txtFirstName;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtLastName;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPhone_number;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtAddress;
    @FXML 
    private Button btnAdd;

    //regular variables
    private Stage ms;

    public UI(Stage stage) {
        this.ms = stage;
    }

    public void stageOne() throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("UI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        //set the stage and scene
        ms.setTitle("Phone Book.");
        ms.setScene(scene);
        ms.show();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void btnAddPerson(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

error:

```
run:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Ohlaph/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PhoneBook/build/classes/phonebook/UI/UI.fxml:8

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at phonebook.UI.UI.stageOne(UI.java:41)
    at phonebook.PhoneBook.start(PhoneBook.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: phonebook.UI.UI
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: phonebook.UI.UI.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 25 more
Exception running application phonebook.PhoneBook
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`btnAddPerson` has no access modifier and is therefore "package private".
If it's called from a different package, it won't be visible.
Have you tried making it `protected`?

Also should you have

```
@FXML private Button btnAdd;
```

?

---

### Edit:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: phonebook.UI.UI.<init>()`
means that you need to have a public constructor *without* a `Stage` parameter. Add this:

```
public UI(){
}
```

You will probably want to have

```
public setStage(Stage s){
  this.ms=s;
}
```

and you'll need another way to set the stage.
This is because the UI construction is done automatically, so FX cannot know what `stage` parameter to pass at construction time. You'll need to set that up that later.

Comment: Hmm OK could you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: I added it to the end of the post.

Comment: Soo...  The original code actually works, however, I had the package and java and fxml file all starting with UI.  I changed the package to .view instead and now it's working fine.  Beginner mistakes I guess.  make the changes you recommended to polish it up!  Thanks!!!!